# Can I add a menu link with a parameter?

Tags: 8, navigation

I would like to add a menu link using the "Link"-Field with Autocomplete, but I would like to add a parameter afterwards.

Pretty much like this:

[image]

...which is not working.

Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a direct answer, but I used the module "Menu Link Attributes" to add a class and used JS to add the parameter:

```
$('#menu ul li a.parameter').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?p=parameter");
});
```

Maybe that's helpful.